# "Explain X to me" questions: How to react?

Tags: discussion, questions

The question mould is:

> How does X work? 
>   I've read the [*Wikipedia article / original paper / documentation / other resource*] but I can't make sense of it. Please explain X to me in plain English.

where X is a concept, algorithm, pattern, etc. (Not a code dump.)

I've come across a number questions fitting this mould. I never really know how to react. The result could perhaps be quite useful, but it doesn't quite seem to be a natural fit for Stack Overflow as a Q&A site.

One reason is, it isn't clear what the appropriate scope of a good answer would be:

- Explain which part? (Some of it? All of it?)
- To what level of detail?

The appropriate result is ill-defined and unbounded: could be anything between a one-liner and a 100-page treatise.

Example*:

- [How does Dijkstra's self-stabilizing algorithm work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435046/how-does-dijkstras-self-stabilizing-algorithm-work)

### Questions:

- What is the appropriate reaction to such a question?
- When is such a question valid?

<sub>* Feel free to edit this if you want to add more examples.</sub>

Comment: Most (if not all) of the questions I saw with this pattern were : 1) off-topic for SO, most likely programmers.SE questions. 2) duplicates of 500+ voted Q/A. I flagged them as such

Comment: If the OP is explaining exactly what they don't understand then the question can be a good one.

Comment: I would try and flesh out specifics using a comment, "What part don't you understand? What information would help you understand?" if it seems salvageable. Otherwise I close as unclear.

Comment: My impression is that the accepted answer in the example lacks from a good question. It should either be more specific or more comprehensive.

Comment: Well, that's a lot better than "I haven't bothered studying any of the documentation.  Write my code for me."

Comment: @ClémentMalet Such 'explain it to me' questions would likely be closed on P.SE too.  The various guidance on this topic on our meta: [Why was my question closed as too broad?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6490/40980) and [Why is research important?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6559/40980) and [Where to start?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6366/40980).  I would also point to a bit that I wrote on MSE: [Is a question that specifically asks for a summary of a broad topic valuable to Stack Exchange?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234663/213963)

Comment: 'I've read the [Wikipedia article / original paper / documentation / other resource] but I can't make sense of it' often means - 'the other students have already copy/pasted the articles, and I want some sucker to write me a different answer that does not match the other submissions'.

Comment: @ClémentMalet [Please stop using Programmers.SE as your toilet bowl](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73382/165773)

Comment: @gnat Be sure that I'm not. Of course "Explain X to me" is likely to be off-topic on any SE website. When I said "with this pattern", I was referring to the fact that these questions are mostly conceptual questions, not "I'm noob tell me everything I need to know to be the tuh boss". (And programmers not being in the off-topic list, I never really flagged it that way)

Comment: @ClémentMalet if you look at that post on MSE, you will see we get the "explain waterfall to me" and "explain scrum to me" questions. We frequently see too broad posts on P.SE and when chasing the trail back find someone on SO saying "maybe this should be on P.SE." Thus, why we jump we we see someone spreading the "all conceptual on P.SE" thoughts. If it's too broad on SO, it's too broad on P.SE and thus shouldn't be migrated regardless of its topicality.

Comment: I think that example question you gave was written before people started downvoting bad questions. I think I would downvote or closevote such a question. It sounds like fancytalk for "The paper is too think and I don't feel like googling an excerpt myself".

Comment: Somehow it came to my mind that these questions should be migrated to http://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/

Comment: Which would you rather have?  More questions like the one you linked, or more of the endless parade of under-specified, highly-localized troubleshooting questions?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: [False dichotomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dilemma)?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: Not really.  The attention span of the community is finite; there's only so much weight the front page can carry.

Comment: see also: [How to handle “Explain how this ${code dump} works” questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253894/839601)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can vote to close it as "unclear what you're asking" if the scope is ill-defined, or "too broad" if the question is decidedly so. Prompt the questioner to add specifics as appropriate.

Such a question can be valid provided the asker has demonstrated research effort, the question is narrowed down enough and the subject matter is on-topic for our site.

Answer (score 22):

The part of the question that makes the biggest difference for me is whether the user is asking for help understanding a *topic* or a *specific resource*. I love questions that say "I have read through resources X, Y, and Z, but still don't understand this concept". Those usually get an upvote from me, provided they're formulated well.

If the question is inverted and instead says, "I have read this resource, and it covers concepts X, Y, and Z. Can you explain the whole document to me?" I will usually flag those as too broad.

You've specified in your question that X is a "concept, algorithm, pattern, etc", so that would fall into the first category I described, and I think those kinds of questions are great as long as they are specific and list at least a few resources that the OP has attempted to understand.

Answer (score 17):

The questioner should indicate which portion of the topic he already understands and which not. Otherwise it's not clear from which point the answer should start. I would refuse to answer "please explain X to me" type questions unless the questioner also mentions specific points he/she doesn't understand.

If this is clear and you don't think the answer would be too long (too broad) or can be found elsewhere (not enough research) then why not writing a great answer.

In the specific linked case the specific question is "I still don't quite get the k-state solution." So one could maybe give an answer detailing the k-state solution (if it is not too long) and then adapt the question towards "How does one obtain the k-state solution in Dijkstra's self-stabilizing algorithm?" if one wanted to.

Answer (score 13):

"**Explain X to me"** is no different from "**Why does this code work/does not work?**". Your reaction should depend on whether additional information is included in the question, i.e. whether any research was made prior to posting this question.

I would argue that including links in the question constitutes research. You can google for your key phrase and include top 5 links, using 1min of your time.

Let's consider the question you linked as an example:

> I have read his seminal paper, Self-stabilizing systems in spite of distributed control. However, I don't quite get how the self-stabilizing algorithm works. I am most interested in his, **'solution' of k-state machines**. The density of the paper is quite intense and I can't make much sense of it. How does this algorithm work in plain English?

I highlighted the part which suggests that OP has in fact done some research. However, I think it is not enough to make a good question. Whether such a question should be answered is up to the community.

I would expect the OP to explain a bit more of what they understand, and what they don't, from the topic they want explained. My reasoning is simple - if they cannot provide a detailed explanation of what they don't understand, there is a high chance they will not be able to provide feedback on the answer (i.e. keep asking questions in comments, without ever getting to the point).