# Interesting scenario of a blog post converted to Q and A

Tags: discussion, specific-question, self-answer, specific-answer, instant-self-answer

When I first saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880654/how-do-asp-net-application-events-work I was curious what specific aspect of the pipeline they were trying to hook into. When I visited the actual question it seemed to be rather vague.

It also was already answered, by the OP, stating they had figured out how the application events "work". It was basically a verbatim reproduction of a blog. The blog post (not written by OP) is from a very credible source. He is a Microsoft MVP (Most Valued Professional) - for those of you not familiar with this, it means he has contributed a lot to helping people with MS related technologies, and some of our top users here are MSMVP's.

That said, the user here basically reproduced the blog post in the form of a question and answer. The answer was posted a mere 4 minutes after the question was posted and at its first iteration contained only 3 lines linking to the blog post (it was later edited to include a paraphrasing of the blog post).

Once looking at all of this, the self answered post, the vague question, the essential duplication of content, and taking into consideration the question and answer were already upvoted I thought at first maybe I should just move on. But something about this pattern irked me.

I considered downvoting it, but then I was not entirely sure that it was warranted as the content isn't really inaccurate even if it smacks of plagiarism. I considered voting to close it as too broad but often if it already answered this has no affect. I thought perhaps I should flag it with a custom message to explain my predicament.

As you can see I am fairly confused on what the correct course of action would be for this post, and so I came here to ask for some guidance on what the community thought of this type of scenario.

Comment: Entering the titular question "how do asp.net application events work?" into Google takes me right to the blog post. It doesn't seem necessary to me to post a question on SO just to link to the blog. It's been there since 2009. It doesn't seem to be going anywhere. I might be persuaded if the OP had more to add, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I don’t have anything against self-answers if they are there to educate other users; I do have some issue with basing a self-answer on the research and content of a third-party who didn’t even agree with having it reposted as a SO question…

Comment: This feels like plagiarism, even if there is attribution.  In essence, this user decided to present someone else's work, without any significant contribution of their own, for their own gains.  Finding a blog post and not finding a corresponding question on SO is not a good reason to post on SO.

Comment: The question isn't a programming problem, it's "how does this code work" without a specific focus.  [This is considered too broad.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797/how-to-deal-with-questions-of-the-type-i-dont-understand-how-this-code-works.)

Comment: Just now it was removed.

Comment: If not for the "plagiarism" issue, I think it's a good question - it's a question I have asked myself. I have just always _assumed_ the answer was "Reflection". That said, I think all that is needed is a comment with a link to the blog post. Pity we can't close questions as duplicates of blog posts.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[image: Unleash the META EFFECT on them - and downvote them into oblivion]

<sub>(you have done well)</sub>

Comment: Wew, I think this answer is a bit too much, bordering on rude.

Comment: It wasn't my intention to have the post "downvoted into oblivion". It was however my intention to get community consensus on this pattern, which is basically the "meta effect". If users had agreed with the pattern, then the post could have been upvoted into !oblivion. I think the action taken just represents the increased attention to the post and that is why I accepted this answer.

Comment: Actually this answer was meant to be ironical, based on what just had happened (25 downvotes on that question!). The hidden message is: *Bringing something up on meta is never wrong*, if you get some attention then the crowd will show you the cumulative right action (which in this case was users sharing your suspicion and voting accordingly).

Comment: *"Bringing something up on meta is never wrong"* You seem to ignore the fact that now the OP will be most likely banned forever from asking, based on the downvotes that were caused by the meta effect.

Comment: @user000001: While the exact rules are not published, a single downvoted question has never question-banned anyone yet. And in this case, the OP does still have about 1K rep, so it hardly matters to him.

Comment: welp question is gone now. meta effect.

Answer (score -5):

I've seen answers that just point to an external resource being received well on Stack Overflow. I used my time to create a short version of the excellent, but long explanation of the question because an user suggested it.

I'm a fan of Stack Overflow, but I feel a bit disappointed because I see people with good intentions focused on the wrong issues. The are a lot of bad quality posts in Stack Overflow, and I think that mine is not one of them.

Finally I want to clarify that I had no intention in taking credit for someone else's work. I was happy to find a great answer to a question I had and wanted to share it because thought it was very good.

Thanks for taking care of Stack Overflow, you guys do a good work. But please don't discourage people trying to contribute to this site. Right know I feel less capable of using my time for helping others.

Comment: Intentions are irrelevant.  The quality of the result is what matters.  That you tried to create something valuable doesn't matter; what matters is whether you actually did create something valuable.  It seems that those that have read it largely felt that it's not, and they're providing that feedback.

Comment: @Servy if that's the case then I'll try to understand why people think that what i felt like a good Q&A is really garbage. Still don't get it but I have to because I don't want to repeat my mistake. Should I delete Q&A? I don't know what's the right thing to do next.

Comment: @agarwaen You can delete it if you like. Doing so will reverse the rep loss from the downvotes for it. I can't tell you the main problem people have with your question. Davidism in then comments on this question mentions that it's too broad, so that might be part of it. Chances are if you don't delete it, users with enough rep will before too long.

Comment: Self-answered questions are totally fine, and the fact that it appeared in a blog is not relevant one way or the other, though it sometimes points to quality problems being more likely.  The point of a self answered question, though, is *the question has to be a good question*, and *the answer has to be a good answer*.  In this case it was too close to simply a blog post - which is not what SO is.

Comment: I think the main issue with the post is that it uses the blog title verbatim, directly copy pasted the code example they use, and then goes on to essentially paraphrase the blog in an answer. While not *exactly* copied, it is so close that it is basically plagiarism. Moreover, were this to be an acceptable pattern, every blog post from people like the original author would be susceptible to having their blogs converted into similar posts. This defeats the purpose of both the site here, and also robs them of traffic and credit regardless of saying "they get the credit" or not.

Comment: @all thanks for your comments. I believe I got the idea

Comment: Lots of calls of plagiarism getting thrown around here, wrongly.  Attribution does defuse plagiarism.  What attribution does not do, however, is give you the right to copy content found on some website outside StackExchange and change its license to CC BY-SA.  **Don't post anything that you do not own the copyright to.**

Comment: The problem with posting a question with the intent of immediately answering it yourself is that there's a good chance that no one is interested in the answer - not even you, since you already know it. Most likely, people interested in that topic are having no trouble finding the original blog post you copied, so copying it into an SO Q&A is of no value. That is not a useful contribution.

Comment: @BenVoigt Definitions of plagiarism do vary somewhat, but it's actually fairly common to consider re-publishing another's works, even with proper attribution, but without adding any additional value, to be plagiarism.  Of course, not all definitions of the term agree on that point, but it's certainly not right to say that it's universally accepted that attribution automatically absolves one of plagiarism.

Comment: @Servy: SO's [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) says "Plagiarism - posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own". Definitions may vary, but I've never seen one that isn't about missing attribution.

Comment: @npostavs From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagiarism): "Common forms of student plagiarism: [...] 10. Relying too heavily on other people’s work. Fails to bring original thought into the text."  From [plagirism.org](http://www.plagiarism.org/plagiarism-101/what-is-plagiarism): "ALL OF THE FOLLOWING ARE CONSIDERED PLAGIARISM: [...] copying so many words or ideas from a source that it makes up the majority of your work, whether you give credit or not (see our section on "fair use" rules)"  Now, as I said, it's not a universally applied clause, but it *is* common to see it.