# What's site policy regarding questions asking for an explanation of potentially malicious code

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, ethics

Someone has posted Word VBA code that they suspect may be malicious and asks for interpretation:

[Malicious Word Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984931/malicious-word-macros)

I can't make heads or tails of it, at a quick glance - it may well be, but I'm not about to try it out.

Should this kind of thing be flagged? Voted closed? Left alone if we don't have a clue?

Comment: Alternatively: [How to deal with questions of the type “I don't understand how this code works](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797/how-to-deal-with-questions-of-the-type-i-dont-understand-how-this-code-works)

Comment: Personally, I'd flag as "too broad", but I'm sure some good Samaritan will jump at the opportunity to interpret that for the OP.

Comment: Yes, that or try to run it, which was part of my concern that I asked so quickly and wondered whether to flag. But if that's policy, then so be it...

Comment: I changed this to support, because it isn't really something the community can discuss per se. I agree with the duplicate closure though.

Comment: @TravisJ So, should I delete it? I have my answer(s)...

Comment: I don't think you need to delete it, I wouldn't vote for deletion and I did upvote your question. I think that since this question is a legitimate one-off situation, leaving it may help serve as a signpost to the duplicate target in the future, which coincidentally is the entire point of duplicate closure :)

Comment: [Also](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions). The consensus seems firm around "close that", even without getting into the "potentially malicious" thing.

Comment: @yivi Yes, the "too broad" is obvious. I do tend to be a bit of a "hand-holder" (comes from supporting Office), so my initial concern is to prevent others from getting hurt. But I suppose, considering this is SO, if they don't know any better then...