# Explain why my code works like it does - on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I've been reading the guidelines
[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
in order to understand what's on-topic and what's off-topic after having my question closed with the comment *Not suitable for this site*.

The question is about a specific programming problem which I'm sure many developers have to solve. It's also obvious that my code and configuration don't work the way they should. Maybe that's why some reviewers mistook it for a debugging question "Why does it not work?"

I don't see it as a debugging question, but more like "Why does it work the way it works?"
I want to understand why that code with that configuration leads to the behaviour it has. I found similar questions about the same behaviour in very different environments so I thought the explanation of the problem might be the same. Links to the related questions are included in the question.

Now there's a notice on the question about the need for debugging details, desired behaviour, shortest code to reproduce the problem, all of which I would understand if it was a debugging question. However, if anyone needs more details about debugging the problem, they most likely cannot answer the question. Debugging details would help find a solution to the problem which is not what I'm looking for.

There are also reasons for not providing the shortest code to reproduce the problem. My code is supposed to interact with a third-party API whose code or configuration I cannot access.

I've edited the question to include the reason why the code doesn't work and I could add the instructions for solving the problem but that seems irrelevant to the question.

What I can conclude is that my closed question is not *clearly* off-topic but I'm not sure if it's on-topic here or if there is a better place for it.

Regarding some arguments, I'll address them here.

**It comes down to teaching you how to debug**

This sounds like a valid argument, at first. But if you look at the typical on-topic questions, you'll see that they come down to teaching you how to program. The only difference I see is that the "teaching you how to program" questions are clearly on topic, whereas "teaching you how to debug" is less clearly there.  If you program, you'll need debugging skills. If you debug, you'll need programming skills. I don't see the value of focusing on one and excluding the other.

**The question is unanswerable** (and therefore off-topic)

Now there is code that is easy to write and then there's code that's hard to write. The same is true about bugs: some are easier to debug than others. There's probably some idea of what questions are too trivial but is there any about a question being too hard? Personally, I think that hard questions can be good questions and shouldn't be downvoted as "unanswerable" or closed as "not suitable". There may be comments along the lines *"more details please!"* begging for more clues about the problem, solution, or something else which is not really relevant to the question. I would interpret these comments in two different ways: 1) Either the question was not clear, or 2) the person making the comment doesn't have the answer. Neither case warrants more details to be added to the question. Sure, the question becomes more answerable by welcoming irrelevant answers but the irrelevant details also make it less clear what kind of answer was really requested.

Comment: Is the question [How to deal with questions of the type “I don't understand how this code works”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278797/11682469) answered by a mod useful? "Too broad" is now "needs more focus".

Comment: I read that question - it is related but not quite on the spot. In my case, the code is not really my code: not the code that causes the problem and not the code the causes the behaviour. What I'd expect of the answer is to help identify the configuration problem based on the behaviour because we don't have access to all the code.

Comment: The answer would come down to teaching you how to debug in general.

Comment: You are expecting technical support, not an answer. This question in its current state is not answerable because you haven't figured out the source of your problem yet. That requires digging. It is the kind of thing you would ask colleagues for help with, not Stack Overflow because the only way to get there is to experiment and poll - in the situation where you can't ask the other party to look in their logs. I agree that "needs debugging details" is the wrong close reason, to me this is a "needs more focus" situation.

Comment: Teaching how to debug - that may be the case sometimes, but not always. I'd expect to be able to answer my own question if I had access to the code on remote servers, in which case I'd have to do a lot of digging. It's also possible that some documentation exists.

Comment: The source of the problem is included in the question - I could include instructions for solving the problem too. What I don't have is an explanation for the behaviour. Having that would help others fix their problem when they face the same behaviour.

Comment: "don't work the way they should" They almost certainly do. It is your expectations that are wrong. If you don't give them & why, we can't address them, and you are just asking for manuals/documentation to be rewritten with no way to specialize to your misconceptions. "Why does it work the way it works?" Because it works the way the manuals/documentation say. Don't ask us to rewrite them. OK, you don't think you are asking that, but you are. You think the code should to do something else, so explain. That includes, give the least code that is code you show is OK extended to code you show isn't.

Comment: Depending on how you see it, you may think that I'm asking others to answer my question but you may also think that I've giving others a chance to contribute something to it. If something is not well documented, a question would direct attention to it and give everyone a chance to contribute to it. The attitude here is certainly different: let's close the question so that no one can contribute. I don't see the problem  with questions aiming to have something documented.

Comment: Is your comment directed to anyone in particular? See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment. (Posters & followers aways get notified.) Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS You are jumping to (wrong) conclusions. PS Find out how the site works & what its goal is.

Answer (score 9):

> Explain why my code works like it does - on or off topic?

It depends on the question. If you present a clear piece of code where you are getting unexpected results, that's an on-topic question.

Even without code, if you present a practical programming related scenario, adequately scoped and with enough details for other users to reproduce; the question would also be on-topic.

> **It comes down to teaching you how to debug**
> This sounds like a valid argument, at first. But if you look at the typical on-topic questions, you'll see that they come down to teaching you how to program.

Actually, no. On-topic question are not about "teaching users how to program". Questions are about practical programming issues, and while of course the site is an *educational* resource of sorts, it certainly can't teach anyone how to program. If fact, it's practically useless for someone who **doesn't already know** how to program. Without being a programmer, it's not possible for one to need assistance with a practical programming issue.

> **The question is unanswerable**

A question needs to have enough information to be able to receive useful answers to be on topic. Without an adequate scope and clear goals, answers that can be useful for future visitors cannot be posted.

---

The problem with this meta-question in general (and with its closing paragraph in particular) is that you ask rather broad question, present some scenario details, but neglect to specify the question where those apply. I think this question would have benefited from you using the [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) and [reopen-closed](/questions/tagged/reopen-closed) tags, and with more detailed information about the question where you are having issues.

In that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205387/why-do-apple-app-store-notifications-get-an-http-30-response), the whole issue revolves about you getting a `301` HTTP response on a request made by an incoming webhook. The webhook is triggered by an in-app purchase on an iOS application, and calls back to your app for a server-to-server notification.

You provide a bit of Symfony code, some logs that show that your server is responding to these `POST` requests with the aforementioned redirect, some details about where you are hosting the Symfony application and who is the TLS certificate provider. On later edits you added a link to Apple's documentation, and then the results for a test you made with `nscurl`.

You say you are looking for "an explanation and a way to reproduce the problem".

But the thing is, nobody can explain you what's going on with the provided details. It's your application (or maybe your webserver) the one returning a redirect response. Neither the code nor the logs you show are enough to explain what's going on (or even where is going on).

For anyone to be able to provide you with a decent answer, you would have to collect more information (which is what I think other users meant by "teaching you how to debug". You need to try to isolate the call, add more logging, use a sandbox to reproduce the call and try to see exactly what's producing the `301` response, maybe use an intermediate server to capture the incoming request, etc, etc, etc.

By the time you did all that legwork, maybe you discovered your issue is not related to Symfony at all, and you could remove the irrelevant code and tags. Or that it was related to Symfony, but completely unrelated to Apache, and so on.

Or maybe, even solve the issue yourself. Many times, all the work required to produce a good question for these harder-than-average problems is enough for us to find the solution for ourselves.

Comment: Programmers can be taught programming. Programmers learn more programming from good answers. I still don't see why learning more about debugging is off-topic.

Comment: Probably because debugging is interactive, iterative, heuristic, and doesn't lend itself at all to the Q&A format. There isn't a single teachable algorithm to follow, just lots of different tools, mental models, habits of thought, and lots of trial & error.

Answer (score 1):

I have voted to reopen your question **as it is now**. It's clear, it shows a lot of research effort, it attempts to solve a specific problem - it's probably in the 99th percentile of quality for questions posted here nowadays.

In terms of providing more information, it's obvious that you physically cannot as much of that information is simply inaccessible to you (in Apple's walled garden). I don't believe that in itself makes the question bad - in a similar vein there have been questions asked here about the rationale behind design choices in certain programming languages, which could only be answerable by people who had a hand in such choices, and those questions have indeed drawn answers from said people and been highly upvoted.

A question that is difficult or potentially impossible to answer (for whatever reason) doesn't deserve closure, in my opinion. It might never attract an answer due to its nature, or might attract low-quality answers from idiots trying their luck - but it can't intrinsically be described as "bad".

---

**However**, the initial draft of your question did show less debugging information and was far less clear as to what result you were trying to obtain. Even in its current state, the question asks numerous sub-questions which are likely to attract low-quality answers only answering one of those sub-questions, not the question as a whole. That's likely why people voted to close the question as "needs more focus".

Those sub-questions in and of themselves are not a bad thing, because you are attempting to learn how to solve your own problem, which is exactly what a true programmer does - but they invite back-and forth conversations between you and people trying to answer, which is a forum-style approach that's orthogonal to the question-and-answer format of Stack Overflow.

The simplest advice I can give to you going forward is **ask one, and only one, question per question**.

---

Regarding the user experience on Stack Overflow, you are not the first to ask for guidelines to be communicated better and sadly you will not be the last. The community has been asking the owners of Stack Overflow for improvements in that area for the better part of a decade, and little has happened, with the result that much of the knowledge of what is considered acceptable conduct or not is very much institutionalised in the people who have been here longest. Unfortunately we can't offer you much help or guidance in that area, except for "stick around Meta and try to learn from osmosis".

The examples that I mentioned of questions being answered by big names in the software development world, are sadly mostly an artifact of the Stack Overflow of yesteryear. For many reasons, the volume of questions on the site has increased drastically  (and the overall quality has declined drastically) while the number of users answering them has not kept pace, with the result that many of the best answerers have simply given up wading through a deluge trying to find something decent to spend their time answering. This is another issue that Stack Overflow management has repeatedly ignored, and again is out of the community's control.

Finally, the ever-increasing number of questions and answers, combined with a barely-increasing base of users curating them, combined with Stack Overflow management continually making it more difficult to remove bad questions and answers, means that those curators are less likely to look long and hard at a question, and more likely to make mistakes, when judging whether to close or not. **I am not saying that is what happened here**, but it is something to keep in mind should you encounter future closures you feel are incorrect: we are only human.

Essentially, there are very few people curating the site nowadays in proportion to the amount of questions - most bad - that pour in, the company controlling Stack Overflow has showed no will to improve this situation, and the result is that those of us left are unable to give our best at all times. We the curators cannot apologise for this, because we are not responsible for the mess.

---

In closing, please don't be discouraged by your experience here - you definitely seem like the kind of user we want to keep around, and you wouldn't be the first who has had a somewhat rocky start on Stack Overflow. All I can advise is a little patience, and a willingness to post on Meta.

Answer (score -3):

This question was inpsired by my closed question [Why do Apple app store notifications get an HTTP 301 response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205387/why-do-apple-app-store-notifications-get-an-http-301-response) but I wanted to make the discussion more general by asking it here without the reference.

I'll have to conclude that the answer to this question is: **Off-topic**.

Regarding the closed question, it is answerable with the details given, and much less. I've solved the problem and I could answer the question myself - but closed questions don't accept any answers. I could answer similar questions, too, without needing more debugging details, and so could anyone else who has some level of expertise in the following: ATS, SSL, Apache/nginx, Cloudflare. Most likely a dev/ops person. Anyone who is unfamiliar with these technologies and topics, would need more debugging details to help them **guess** what the explanation might be. But I wasn't asking for more guesses. I did my fair share of the guesswork before posting the question. Moreover, how could anyone unfamiliar with these technologies teach anyone how to debug in the given environment? The suggestions that have so far come from a person unfamiliar with the environment only reveal the ignorance of the person while derailing the discussion. It's fair to say that if you're familiar with the topic and know how to debug in this environment, you can easily find the explanation to the problem without guessing or replicating the behaviour.

The suggestion that all and only the relevant details should be included in the question is ridiculous. If you haven't solved the problem, you most likely can't define the set of relevant details so that all of those and only those are included. If you've solved your problem, you don't come here asking off-topic questions about it. Just look at the related open, on-topic questions that I referenced in my closed off-topic question. Those people asking them don't know what details are relevant to their problem. The person who knows the answer will know what's relevant and what's not and what's missing.

People who review these questions also don't seem to know what details are relevant and what's missing. Even irrelevant details can add value to the question for those who like guessing: they can rule out some wrong guesses when they see code that does not cause problems. The vague requests for debugging details also speak to the ignorance of the reviewers who, in my opinion, should have a more professional attitude and not jump into conclusions too soon. That they can't answer the question doesn't mean that no one can, and it certainly doesn't mean that the question is off-topic as a consequence.

The requirement that there should be enough details for anyone to reproduce the bug is fair but it applies poorly to some questions. I could add enough details there only by stating that default or minimal configuration can be used in the environment described in the question. Setting up the environment would still take days if not weeks, starting from having your App store app reviewed multiple times, then implementing in-app payments, etc. etc. etc. And when you finally have everything set up, you can only reproduce the described behaviour. Of course, then you could start to debug and that'd help you guess, but it's unnecessary if you want to come up with an explanation and answer the question.

As far as the user experience on SO goes, it might be a good idea to update the page about "What can I ask here", just to make it clear to future users that they shouldn't be asking questions like mine here. I spent a lot of time on it, getting downvotes and comments that needed flagging, while getting zero help on the issue. I imagined I'd just wait and see if anyone comes up with an answer before I solve the problem and if not, I could answer my own question, having done it before. But no, the first reviewer removes the tags that might help certain experts find the question: SSL is central to the answer, while anyone who implements Apple in-app purchases would be familiar with the domain of the problem. Then the question is closed, preventing anyone from posting answers.

Even this question about the relevance of my closed question seems to be worth lots of downvotes. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to apologise for posting off-topic questions but I'll just say that you've made your point. If you (= SO users) want to be helpful, update the guidelines so that people don't have to waste their time.

Comment: Meta's rules are different to the main site. Votes here generally indicate how much the community agrees or disagrees with the content of a question or answer.