# Why was my question closed for not being reproducible/caused by a typo?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, closed-questions

First of all, I just want to make it clear that I'm not here to rant about my question being closed or demanding my post be reopened. I'm just curious.

The post in question is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66226175/indexing-an-unsigned-long-variable-and-printing-the-result). The question is a bit too weird to properly explain in one line, so you might have to see the post itself to understand what I'm asking. I noticed two close votes were cast yesterday and today, the post was finally closed for not being reproducible and/or caused by a typo. This is the feedback I got: [This question was caused by a typo or a problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpT8c.png)

Now I'm not sure how this is not reproducible and/or caused by a typo (maybe not reproducible because it would have to be tweaked to run on a system where a `long` is 32 bits), but maybe the feedback makes sense. The question *is* a very weird one, and even though I tried my best to make an answer that explained the question, it could still be useless and/or too confusing for future readers. If there's anyone who understands why my question was closed, could you explain why to me so I can make sure this doesn't happen in the future?

Comment: Note that this is only the _dominant_ reason. Maybe one of the three voters has chosen a different reason. I don’t know why this was closed for this reason. Sometimes a question may be closed for being caused by a “mental typo” (rather than an actual typo), but I can’t think of a way that this would apply to your question. I’ve voted to reopen.

Comment: Ah ok, I hadn't thought of the possibility that someone voted for another reason. Thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: Also, [relevant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797/how-to-deal-with-questions-of-the-type-i-dont-understand-how-this-code-works). Not saying the closure was appropriate or inappropriate, not keen on wading these waters. Just giving additional context.

Comment: Yes, it is true that I wasn't able to pinpoint a specific issue in the code (mainly because I didn't understand a single thing about the program) and the original title of the question was vague before it was edited by another user. This could be a possibility.

Comment: From my experience this close reason is sometimes used when something minor (therefore typo) and *dumb* is attempted. If similar issues happen often (e.g. to beginners) then such question may have a value, but the problem is that you won't be able to find that post ever again anyway. I would personally just delete such a question as soon as I get a hint in comments.

Comment: @Sinatr that would seem to make some sense. The program in the question is pretty dumb and hacky after all. However, I got no such hint in the comment section ever, the post was just closed. As of now, the question has been reopened, but if it is closed again, I guess I'll delete the post.

Comment: Stack Overflow's current banners that explain close reasons are mostly garbage (poor explanation of what the reason means, and lacking links for more detail), but unfortunately the community doesn't have control of how they present things.

Comment: But yes, in general when identifying the problem is the same as solving the problem, it's hard to write a question that will let future readers with the same problem find it.  (*Like* a typo, but other brain-farts are possible like forgetting to hit "save" before compiling, or being in the wrong directory, stuff like that.)

Comment: @PeterCordes yeah, I guess that is a possible reason for the specific message.

Comment: Implementation-defined behavior questions can be considered unreproducible if no one knows the underlying settings to run though. By providing at least 1 specific setting on the question that is always reproducible, then the closing shouldn't have happened. Though at the moment, the question looks like a fun/trick question without any practical purpose (perhaps on [Codegolf.SE] though).

Comment: @AndrewT. I hadn't thought about it that way, so that is true. I just wish the original people who voted to close mentioned a reason in the comments, because I only found out about the implementation-defined behavior thing after my question was closed and someone commented on my answer. At the time, there were no such comments which told me about any such issue.

Comment: Just from observation, people will sometimes use this close reason if they believe OP has a simple *misunderstanding* that is unlikely to help others. Like a problem caused by thinking `0x12` and `12` are the same thing, its not a mis-type and its certainly reproducible, but it has the same flavor of being a trivial fix. I don't think that's the case here, even if the answer may be seen as simple once you know the trick.

Comment: @kmdreko yeah, I found out what was going on pretty quickly after I converted the decimal number to its hex equivalent.

Comment: Actually, all three close voters picked the same reason. I don’t seen _why_ they picked that reason however.

Comment: I had a  question closed with a similar message containing the word "typo".  In my case I was using a tool (viz. dbVisualizer) to access Microsoft-SQL (TSQL-language).  The problem would not be reproducible unless one was using dbVisualizer, so I gave up on the question.  I got downvoted, then I deleted it...

Comment: Perhaps the three people tried this program with a certain compiler and got a different output. I've tested on gcc and clang only, don't have access to any other compilers.

Comment: The linked question asks quite a lot of questions in the body. It might need more focus.

Comment: @Trilarion I think you're thinking that my questions are "What significance does the number `506097522914230528` hold?", "How does this result in `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7`?", and "what exactly is being indexed?". While it is true that these are different questions, I don't think I could divide them into separate posts or ask one question out of the three specifically, since they are all very specific to the program in question and they wouldn't have any context otherwise. If you could tell me how this question could be more focused though, I'd love to edit it to make it more clear.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 The input number is not very specific to the program, just influences the output. The program would work with any other number (would just deliver a different output, which wouldn't be more or less instructive). The important part seems to be "what exactly is indexed". A question that would focus on this part would maybe give a simpler example of the effect. A focused question could be "what does *(((unsigned char *) &foo) + i) do?" (that's what you really want to know) or something similar. That question might already been answered before (not sure).

Comment: @Trilarion my main question is less like "what does *(((unsigned char *) &foo) + i) do?" and more like "why exactly is a long being indexed?" And since that is the real question I had, I feel like the number `506097522914230528` is relevant to that. Keep in mind, when I first asked this question, I was completely clueless about everything in the program. Therefore, this seemingly random number seemed to hold some sort of special significance at the time, due to it magically printing `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7` after being casted to a `char *` and indexed for some reason.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 "due to it magically printing 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7" Yes, but there is nothing magically about 01234567, it could as well be 65489475436 or just 1, depending on the input and the program wouldn't change. There might be a simpler way of presenting the problem. Basically you break down the big problem of understanding the whole program into smaller, more focused ones and the most difficult part is the *(((unsigned char *) &foo) + i) line and maybe also how are longs are stored in memory. If you solve that you can understand the program for every possible input number.

Comment: Hmm, you're definitely not wrong. I'll see if I can edit the question to isolate the big question out. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Trilarion I have edited my question and it is now (hopefully) more focused on `*(((unsigned char *) &foo) + i)` specifically.

Comment: @philipxy you're not wrong, and as you and Trilarion have shown, my question did indeed lack focus. I admit in hindsight that my question could have shown more research and effort. At the time, I felt that my findings were not helpful and thus not too relevant. I feel that my question sould have been closed in the first place for that reason, in which case I would have tried to improve what was actually wrong with my post instead of having to ask this question on meta out of confusion. Not reproducible/typo was a very vague reason, and I feel like lack of focus would have helped more.

Comment: @philipxy Yes, that is true and a possibility. I'm trying to make my question focus on that one part specifically now too.

Comment: @AndrewT. You're right, we get a lot of reposted "fun/trick questions" that are indeed quite useless, with no practical purpose whatsoever.  This one, I thought, was different: except for the assumption of a 64-bit long, it was well-written and quite portable, and potentially a real eye-opener and a learning experience for a new programmer -- as indeed it was for our reluctant hero here, mediocrevegetable.  My hat is off to the teacher who originally devised the program.  (But I admit I have a particular fondness for big numbers to be interpreted differently. 5793833326658930787389065751923.)

Answer (score 28):

I thought it was a fine question, and I haven't read the (vast!) number of comments that have been posted on it since yesterday, but I suspect the reason it was closed as "not reproducible" boils down to this fact: the "Vote to close" dialog does not have a radio button for "This question doesn't meet my standards for what we should be discussing here."

I don't know about other tags, but there are still some *very* strongly held minority opinions under the [c] tag for what is and is not allowed to be said.  One such opinion is that *you must not write any code that depends on any aspect of unspecified, implementation-defined, or undefined behavior, under any circumstances, ever*.  (I may be exaggerating, but only slightly.)  Moreover, unless you are a high-rep regular, it is best not even to talk about these concepts, because you will probably fail to talk about them in properly draconian terms, meaning that an overworked, underappreciated pedant will have to swoop in and correct you.

The, er, question in question discussed some low-level, and, yes, implementation-defined behavior that was nevertheless quite instructive.  But evidently the fact that it was implementation-defined roused the ire of the strict-portability-or-die vanguard, although somehow in their excitement they never managed to properly describe what the implementation-defined aspect actually was.  (For some reason they got bogged down in discussions of alignment and strict aliasing and other unrelated matters.)

Comment: Indeed, I had no idea of the implementation-defined and undefined behavior that was in this program at first. I got overwhelmed with the large number of comments too, and I didn't understand some of the words that were being thrown around. I definitely learned some things though, so that's a plus I guess.

Comment: "...unless you are a high-rep regular, it is best not even to talk about these concepts..." I understand that you only describe the thoughts of others but this comes across as particularly peculiar. I though that SO is for asking questions about difficult programming stuff and undefined behavior that nevertheless compiles would seem like it firmly belongs to the class of questions that should be asked (at least once) on SO. This "don't talk about undefined behavior until you know what your doing" should only apply to answers and not to questions.

Comment: I agree with what @Trilarion said. Even if the answer to the question is simply, "This is undefined/implementation-defined behavior, and will go wrong in so many ways that you don't even want to know," it's still a valid question and still deserves to be answered here.

Comment: @Trilarion You're right, and indeed, if someone were to ask, "Is `*p++ = f(*p)` undefined?", it would probably be fine.  But hardly anyone ever asks that question.  What people usually ask is either "What's the correct result?" or "Why didn't it give me the result I expected?" or "Why is it undefined?", and those questions tend to go very badly, and/or to get closed. (And, to be sure, those last three questions are all basically duplicates by now.)

Comment: If using implementation-defined behavior was a valid close reason, then to begin with we'd have to close down all questions about Linux and Windows programming.

Comment: "the "Vote to close" dialog does not have a radio button for "This question doesn't meet my standards for what we should be discussing here."" - I remember seeing a discussion about this before, and the conclusion was **if there is no radio button for a particular close reason then it is not actually a valid close reason and you should not close questions for that reason!**

Answer (score 17):

My question has been closed again (this time by my approval) and comments and votes have mostly stopped coming. It seems like the dust has settled, so I just want to post a self-answer to this post too, just to tell my final opinion and a sort of update.

The first time my question was closed, I was definitely confused. Looking back, it was possibly because some people tried my program on a different implementation/system where they got a different output (maybe because a `long` is 32 bits on some systems, for example). I still find it strange that all three apparently voted to close because of the same reason, but @SteveSummit and @philipxy present some possibilities too.

In hindsight, I agree that the post should have been closed, but probably for lacking focus. I definitely wrote less than I should have, mainly because I didn't think it would be helpful (yes, bad excuse), and that I wasn't expecting this to become a lesson in pointers, so I didn't delve too deep into that kind of research. Furthermore, I was indeed phrasing my question in such a way that I was asking many questions, leaving my real question unclear. I think the question has improved a lot since then, but yes, at the time, it could have been closed for lacking focus.

Anyway, the post was reopened, I started getting a slew of downvotes and upvotes alike. At some point, I guess the downvotes mostly stopped. Comments started coming too, and there were *lots*. Nothing like this had ever happened to me before, very complex words were being thrown around, and I was left answering all of them to the best of my ability. People gave suggestions and I improved my post along the way. A troll came and gave a useless joke answer (thankfully it was downvoted and deleted swiftly).

Today, there were more upvotes, more comments and more edits to the post. About a few minutes ago, I got a notification asking if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810417/when-is-casting-between-pointer-types-not-undefined-behavior-in-c) gave me the answer I wanted. The question talks a lot about undefined behavior with pointers in C. I chose to approve this and as of now, my question has been marked as a duplicate.

The main reason I approved the post (apart from the answers helping the program in my question seem somewhat more understandable) was that, on its own, I don't think this would be a very helpful post in the future. It asks a very specific question and it is unlikely someone will stumble upon this post in the future. The comments on my question and answer were very informative and talked about a lot of different things, so I didn't want that to go to waste. Now that this question is linked to the duplicate question, hopefully someone will stumble upon it and find some nice information. I was also very overwhelmed by the amount of traction my post had gained. Anyways, now it's all settled down and everything is pretty much over.

**EDIT:** things have changed since I posted this answer. For an update, see Lundin's post.

Comment: It's nice to see that you reflect on your experience here. SO is a collaborative effort, as such you will never get a perfectly clear response, questions can be closed that shouldn't be, comments can be inappropriate and joke answers can be given, only in the mean over many votes and many actions does it become a high quality resource. What I realized most about your question was that a) it stopped short, it didn't really pinpointed the issue you had and b) it didn't show any research of the issue. Both would have made this question either a great question or non-existing at all, because you..

Comment: ..would have found the duplicate for yourself. Pointer operations and type casts in C can lead to undefined behavior but still compile and therefore one should be extra careful with them when programming in C. My background is Java and Python, but this is the main lesson I take away from that. And research and pinpointing problems is important because very likely you're not the first to encounter a problem. On the other hand, if you do the pinpointing and researching and really don't find anything, that's what experts are there for. If you invest lots of time and energy, others will do too.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your points. Hopefully, I'll make sure to do more research before asking another such question and better phrase my answer. These three days have definitely been a unique experience, and I think I can safely say I've taken away some good lessons from it.

Comment: IMO, your question and its self-answer are incredibly useful as **examples** of how implementation-specific behaviour might manifest with pointer casting. Thus I think having it marked as a dupe of the more canonical question is absolutely the right thing to do. Regardless though, your question and answer in their current form are both of high quality - thank you for making the effort to bring them up to the standards we wish more content here would exhibit, thanks for "toughing it out" to get to that stage, and thanks for being the kind of user we love to have here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the kind comment, means a lot. I _do_ indeed hope my post can help in the future. There were indeed a lot of edits, but I think the result is far better than what it originally was, and I was helped a lot in the process. For that, I am grateful.

Comment: It was closed for completely wrong reasons. This should have been closed as one of many duplicates if anything. I believe I answered exactly the same question just one week back. Anyway, I have re-opened the question. Might post an answer too, if only to prevent this from getting further "moderated" to oblivion...

Comment: I'll say again that there was nothing wrong with your original post.  You've been a very good sport about responding to some extremely (IMO) misguided criticism.  Your original post was "poor", and the rewritten one is "better", only under some wildly unrealistic assumptions about how real people actually talk about and learn programming.

Answer (score 10):

Arriving a bit late to this discussion, going through edit history.

- You ask a question that does indeed contain some forms of implementation-defined behavior. Well, boo-hoo, we get at least 100 questions in the C tag per day which does. This is *not* a valid reason to close a question.

  One valid reason is "simple typos", such as for example the endless `scanf("%d", myint)` with missing `&` beginner questions. But this question cannot be dismissed as a typo, nor can it be dismissed as utter beginner stuff that can be answered by reading chapter 1 in a beginner-level book. In fact there's misc dirty details on the advanced side of things, the implementation-defined behavior in itself being one of them.

  So your question was incorrectly closed in edit 3 and correctly re-opened in edit 4.
- Another valid close reason is duplicate. And this question can easily be hammered down as a duplicate, I don't know how many questions of this nature I've answered myself and that's just me. In fact I got so annoyed over answering this over and over the other week, so I went ahead and wrote a self-answered Q&A FAQ regarding endianess and type punning through character pointers. I posted it on another site than SO but link to it now and then.

  If someone were to find a good duplicate and close this question, that would have been  correct moderation and the question should then stay closed (given that the dupe target was of better quality than your question).

  This is the reason why I down-voted the question personally, it has been asked and answered many times before and therefore shows lack of research. Yeah I know it's a self-answered Q&A, but you aren't focused on teaching in the answer, you are just explaining the specific code snippet. Your answer doesn't even mention endianess/little endian, which a good answer would - it's basically what the question is all about.
- You did some good edits, then the question was closed again (by yourself and another user), with a dupe target [When is casting between pointer types not undefined behavior in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810417/when-is-casting-between-pointer-types-not-undefined-behavior-in-c)

  That is *not* a good dupe target as it drags in every manner of pointer type not related to the original question. The dupe target is a much broader big picture question and it doesn't even mention the special pointer/lvalue conversion rules that apply here.

  So I used my C badge "dupe hammer" privilege to rollback and re-open the question.

I have now also posted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66263159/584518) myself, which doesn't as much focus on explaining the result, as the various language-lawyer stuff that people were yelling about in comments. Hopefully that will put the language lawyers to rest (proof-reading by fellow language lawyers much appreciated).

Comment: I read your answer and it is very useful and helpful, so thank you for taking the time out to write that. I apologize for not reading the FAQ or finding similar questions, I was not focusing on the endianness and not really focusing on the type punning much before I asked this question, mainly because I hadn't thought that deep into this question at the time. When I first saw this program, I simply assumed it to be a joke program which I simply couldn't work my head around. The thought of these concepts that are being tossed around in the comment section hadn't even come to my mind.

Comment: I'll also edit my answer to mention the endianness too, thank you for bringing that up.

Comment: Arriving at this discussion only after it got highlighted in 'Hot Meta Posts', I remember seeing the question, noting the first three comments (which basically converted the large decimal number to hex — over-simplifying a bit) and agreeing with the thought processes behind them, and then I simply moved on.  I'm more than a little surprised to find so much controversy about a routine question with a routine answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, a lot has happened since my original question. I agree that my post has become a bit controversial after being closed and reopened twice, along with the number of downvotes and upvotes it has gotten. I, too, meant to ask a routine question. I never expected/intended for it to get so controversial, and I can't say I'm entirely pleased with how everything has unfolded in the past three days.

Comment: I agree that the particular duplicate used to close was a poor choice. I did comment with other links that are appropriate. What you rolled back were appropriate tags.

Comment: @philipxy Well, implementation-defined behavior is not a valid tag. That's something the question _contains_, not something that the post _is about_. Arguably it _should_ be about that, or more specifically about endianess and type punning, but that wasn't the case from the start.

Comment: It is about implementation-defined behaviour, since the behaviour of the code & accessing what the char \* points to is implementation-defined behaviour. The post was always about why the observed behaviour happened.

Comment: @philipxy But it isn't the access that's implementation-defined, it is the byte order and size of a `long`. Like so many other questions on the site, the result depends on compiler and system.

Comment: What an access returns is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 2):

Less-experienced C programmers may have run the code & not got your output, hence "not reproducible". (Sufficiently-experienced C programmers would know that, as I commented on your self-answer, this can happen since the code is subject to "implementation-defined behavior"--a technical term. Presumably they wouldn't close as "not reproducible".) That is what the close notice said is a reason for closing. Why didn't you think, if there's no typo, then at least one person thinks this is not reproducible? (Rhetorical.) Then you could edit it & say, I'm told this may not be reproducible but I don't know what part of this isn't reproducible. (And, I researched the following bits of code not being reproducible & ....)

Lack of focus is a close reason, and you don't say what is the first subexpression that you don't, having researched, understand. So although one could know the language perfectly & not understand what a program is doing & ask about it, people might have felt that you should have pinned down your question to the 1st thing you didn't understand, supported by your saying what you understood before that point, justified by referencing documentation. In comments here you say your "real question" was "why exactly is a long being indexed?"; what stopped you from answering yourself? (Rhetorical.)

I voted to reopen yesterday when I commented re implementation-defined behaviour, I wasn't troubled, and now you have upvotes on the linked question & its self-answer. But the more I've composed here & there re how it could be improved & considered unfocused or unresearched I wonder how in so voting I was so ... compassionate. (Understand that all my comments here & there apply to & could be commented on many, many questions, that are poor unfocused unresearched code dumps. SO/SE Inc poorly educates askers.)

PS On your linked question & self-answer I commented further on making your question more focused & on researching, including researching researching--including for how to search & for good documentation.

PS Ask exactly 1 (concise specific researched non-duplicate) question in a question post. Exactly one question mark. Don't ask subsidiary/example wonderings or rhetorical questions. It just makes the post hard to follow. Find another way to express what you mean.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are on about. The only impl.defined behavior here is the size of long and CPU endianess. Everything else is well-defined as far as I can see. I have re-opened the post.

Comment: @Lundin Typo in my message, I meant implementation-defined not undefined. (As earlier in my post.) (Implementation-defined implies readers may not get the same results as in the post.) Re the duplicate I suggested for closing after posting this, it has undefined in the title, but it answers the question. I also listed some other more general & specific duplicate candidates whose titles include implementation-defined, see my comments there; but it's easy to find others.