# Post quality? Site etiquette?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, downvotes, etiquette, question-quality

I'm a long time lurker, a very recent poster. I've been active in other forums and feel like I generally have a really positive experience. But here, it seems that I'm off the mark a bit somehow and was hoping for a little insight.

I'm a newb when it comes to coding outside of some random things here and there like AppleScript, using REGEX in Google Sheets, etc. But even those things, I would never even claim to be anything more than intermediate level.

I was trying to figure out how to do something in an AppleScript, and found an old post here that seemed like it was going to help me, but there was a part of it that after researching for several hours, I just didn't understand. And since this site doesn't let you comment until you've got a rep of 50, I was forced to just re-ask the question again, to which I linked to the original.

[How can I wait for a shell script to complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72413429/applescript-wait-for-shell-script-to-complete)

I didn't receive any answers or comments but kept tinkering and testing my guesses until something worked. Then I posted my results. ...but my post was downvoted? Can anyone here tell me if I'm doing something wrong? I actually felt like it was a pretty concise post that completed the original question for those, like me, who might need more clarity.

Comment: Stack Overflow is NOT a forum. "Can anyone here tell me if I'm doing something wrong?". Honestly, the only thing wrong with your question, is that it contains an ton of extra noise.

Comment: I understand that a single downvote seems more significant when you don't have that many posts yet, but it really only reflects one person's opinion about the post.

Comment: Can I delete the comments under your question and answer already? Have you incorporated this information into your answer or are these comments only temporary and no longer necessary? Please note that comments are ephemeral.

Comment: @SecurityHound so, basically, be less ...uh.. colloquial in my approach, you're saying? Which is funny to me, because I had to train myself to be more "on eggshells" instead of direct elsewhere, or drama ensues. This might just be a breath of fresh air!

Comment: @Dharman sure! I can delete them myself, actually. I'm starting to get the picture here now. Although, someone edited my title and a few other things that I think actually make it less direct. I may undo those.

Comment: @DasKraut - Here are examples of what you don't need to say since they are implied, "Good Morning", "I would appreciate any help in this matter", or honestly "Please".  Now that does not mean you shouldn't write formally, be direct with regards to what your asking, provide enough specific details to answer the question, while just being concise enough to ask your question. When you submit a question you are not having a discussion about a topic, you are asking a question about something specific.

Comment: Related: *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/)* and [Stack Overflow is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115) not [a forum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36828) (more like *deliberative assembly*).

Comment: @PeterMortensen thanks; that first one is a better reference than what I've been using. I'll edit it into my answer.

Comment: "I was forced to just re-ask.." You said you didn't understand one detail but that forced you to re-ask the whole question? I don't understand that. Why didn't you just ask for the stuff that you didn't understand and explained why that other question and answers didn't sufficiently help you?

Comment: Congrats on doing almost everything else correctly so far, by the way. Lurking before doing, writing a follow-up question linking to the previous one, providing necessary details in the question itself, researching and self-answering, writing a very open minded meta post (on meta, no migration needed)... yeah. The only thing for the future is to not answer with only code but also an explanation. Usefulness is pretty much the main quality gauge that we have, code without an explanation tends to not be super-useful.

Comment: @Trilarion The reason I said the whole "re-ask" part is because I though it would have been more hopeful and less cluttered to have been able to follow up on that post itself instead of in this fragmented fashion. Also, I was hoping that showing the context of my code would help get to my specific answer, which is slightly different from the original post, and showing how I implemented their info into mine... while ALSO addressing my assumption on what the issue was. So, I was trying to tackle a lot with very little in order to be precise. But it turns out, I could be more precise.

Comment: @Gimby Thanks! I genuinely hope to be a useful part of communities instead of just another blubbering mouther running around yelling at empty rooms. haha know what I mean? But I appreciate the acknowledgement, thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no telling why people downvote things; they are not required to explain, and don't always volunteer. There are good and bad reasons to downvote questions.

I tried to edit the question to make it read as well as possible for the site. The primary point to make here is that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**; we do not want ["noise"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/) in the post - this means: saying hello or thanks; talking about how frustrated you are with the problem; talking about your level of experience with the tools involved; talking about the [urgency](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569) of the task; or *anything else* "meta" like this. In other words, we **only** want text that directly helps to understand either **the problem**, or **the question** being asked about it.

In some cases, a brief motivation is useful ("I want the code to do X because I will use it for Y"), because it can help answerers understand exactly what you mean, or confirm if you have an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Normally, it is better to wait to be asked for this. People will ask whenever X is either really weird ("why would you want to do that?") or they've seen that XY problem before ("I've seen a lot of people assume that they need to do X in order to accomplish Y; it is a misguided approach").

The second issue here is the *focus* of the question. I edited a few sentences that were expressing a general confusion; in my replacement, I tried to preserve the part where you expressed confusion about what part of the code does. However, this sort of thing makes the question less suitable for Stack Overflow. For one, it is a *separate question* from "how do I make the script wait until the other process completes?". For another, we [can't help you with it, because we don't know why you are confused](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797).

Finally, there is a minor issue of *applicability*. If the question is specifically about how to make the AppleScript wait for another shell script to complete, then a *really good* question has code that:

1. focuses on that question, and the problem in context (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
2. is *generic* enough that other people who find the question with a search engine, will *be able to recognize* that this code matches what they are trying to do, and is not just some other random person's personal debugging request.

As for the answer, it could use some *explanation*. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for some guidance, and also try to put yourself in the shoes of someone else who had the same problem. Will they understand why the code change fixes the problem? *How does* it fix the problem? Can you *describe* what you are changing and why, rather than just *showing* the exact edits? (Edits like this are hard to understand. Even just showing the corrected version of the code is clearer.)

Comment: I'm looking over the edits folks have made. ...so, no explanation either? Got it. I haven't read the how-to yet, but promise I will ASAP, generally speaking, I like to try to give a reason behind why/how I did something, just as a side note to help others understand, if they need it. Would it be ok to do that in the comments like I did on my post?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand the second comment. "no explanation either?" No explanation *of what*? And *what about* the lack of explanation? You *should* include explanation in your answer, about *how* the changes solve the problem.  If you mean "I hoped someone would explain the edits": it's unusual for people to comment about edits they made, except for a specific tutorial purpose. The system has a box to input a reason for edits, but seeing that information is a special privilege. As for comments on your own answer, please put as much into the answer itself as makes sense to do.

Comment: Yup, I see now. I thought someone removed my explanation, but they just moved it to my answer... which, funny enough, is where I originally had it, but then due to some other misunderstandings of mine on site etiquette, I thought they weren't welcome, and had moved to comments. Blah. Ok, I think I'm slightly less of a moron now. Thanks for the guidance. ‍♂️