# Guidance on asking a 'How does this code work' question

Tags: discussion

I need to evaluate the efficiency of a piece of code and find a way to improve it, but I am having a difficult time understanding the need for one part of it.

So, I would like to ask a question, but after having read [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797/how-to-deal-with-questions-of-the-type-i-dont-understand-how-this-code-works) I feel my question may not be welcome.

Are there criteria under which a question of this nature would be deemed acceptable? I do feel that my question would be rather more specific than the example given in the other meta question.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily see a problem with: "Is this chunk of code redundant?" or some such question if the code in question is somewhat small. Obviously it still needs to be well written

Comment: Not knowing what you want to ask you did see : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271469/1699210 and [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278797/how-to-deal-with-questions-of-the-type-i-dont-understand-how-this-code-works#comment128536_278797) comment?

Comment: I did not see either of those @bummi, they do seem to point that as long as I can write the question well that I should be OK, Thanks.

Comment: I guess my biggest worry is the requirement to show research, I honestly don't even know what to search for the code in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"How does this code work" is categorically off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Present it as a "review my code" question (with a focus on performance), and ask it on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.