# Is it OK to ask for help understanding a snippet from PHP book and cite text from there here?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes when reading programming books I stumble upon stuff that I cannot fully understand. I'm eager to ask SO community for help. However, it's rarely possible without citing some text from the book as is.

Is it OK to cite such stuff here copyright-wise? And anything-else-wise?

Comment: Lots of hurdles: The title needs to be searchable, the content of the question needs to be complete enough to give us the information if we don't have the book; and the question needs to be useful to others, as well as it must be a question that someone other than the book's authors can answer.

Comment: I got your point. But still what about copyright issue?

Comment: ... though none of that matters if the reader doesn't have permission to post the content in the first place.

Comment: Unless asked *very* well, "How does this work" questions are generally closed.  Please see, for example, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278797 and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271468.

Comment: I read the links and fully agree with it. Such questions as mine are really not appropriate here as SO is not a help site but a Q/A site.

Comment: We're not copyright lawyers; but I imagine this would fall under fair use.  But again, we're not copyright lawyers; we can only respond to DMCA requests. Your biggest hurdle is what I've mentioned, not the outside chance we may receive a DMCA request.