# Are questions in the form of "How do I explain something for a X-year-old" valid?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes I can see some questions are in the form like : "How do I explain xxx... to a X-year-old (eg.5-year-old)?"

Examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424655 (now deleted)
- [Explain to me LinkedList class with Node Class like you would to a 5 year old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312467)
- [What is a PHP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692223)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324991 (now deleted)

My question is, is the additional requirement "understandable for 5-year-old" valid for a question? If not, are these types of questions on topic?

I ask about it because I also found some questions of these types closed currently:

- [How to explain dependency injection to a 5-year-old?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638919)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694204
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855646 (now deleted)

and don't know if the additional requirement does a matter.

Comment: The last example is a 13 year old, I guess he grew up :)

Comment: It is just a technique that questioners use to stop users from voting to close the question because it is RTFM.  They don't want to read the manual, it takes time.  Saving programmers time is what this site prides itself on so you can't *really* find fault with the approach.  But you are certainly allowed to not like it, don't hesitate to vote.

Comment: Saving time overall, eg. where a question is asked of a problem that is not covered by easily-available documentation, and an answer is provided quickly by a contributor who has already solved that very problem, is great:)  Outsourcing boring research and documentation comprehension, ie. just moving X amount of work to someone else for no pay, is NOT great at all:((

Comment: Such children, or adults with the software development comprehension of such a child, are NOT professional or enthusiast programmers and have no place on SO.

Comment: Sounds like someone's working in an office with a bunch of brand new MBAs.

Comment: [How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6630/31260)

Comment: The 5-year old phrase is kind of synonymously used for "in laymans terms". It means that the questioner has not much knowledge about the subject which may be a sign of not enough research. While I appreciate if somebody gives a bit of background on a question and on himself I would prefer to have it not in the title and a bit more specific like how much of the topic does he/she know already. The real age (if it is relevant) could maybe be mentioned in a comment or in the profile page. Not all of these questions need to be closed but some could be edited instead.

Comment: reddit is leaking o_O http://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive

Comment: @MichaelDibbets - I assumed it was a reference to the movie *Philadelphia*.

Comment: In my opinion all possible questions should be valid.

Comment: related: [“Explain X to me” questions: How to react?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271468/839601)

Answer (score 38):

We could just dissect them here and see what we think of the question on its own merits.

[The first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424655/how-do-you-explain-oauth-2-0-to-a-five-year-old):

> ... How could you explain OAuth 2.0 to a five-year old, that is, in easily understandable words and in a comprehensive way, without over-simplifying your answer? Any suggestions?

The premise of the question is, "can someone explain OAuth 2.0 to me in a simple and concise way?"  The net result is that this question is **too broad**, as there would be a lot of discussion that would be required to talk about a concrete implementation of OAuth, its strengths, and its flaws.

[The second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312467/explain-to-me-linkedlist-class-with-node-class-like-you-would-to-a-5-year-old):

> ... I have googled a lot of sites trying to understand how to construct a linkedlist and to be able to call it in main but for some reason its just not sticking. that being said I have the following code, am i doing it wrong? how do i insert a number into data and how do i move from one node to the next? and how do i call the node class in main and print out the data values?

What we have here:

- Lack of understanding of a concept (to be explicit, I'm ***not*** chastising them for this)
- Unclear question (am I doing it wrong?)
- Unfocused question (how do I do X and Y and Z?)

The fact that they want it explained to them simply belies the problem that the question isn't very good at all.  However, [the answer provided *is*.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29312597/1079354)

In either event, it's "unclear" what's being asked since there are a lot of things being asked.  They want to see if their code works and how to actually use it, but quite frankly, I'm not so sure we should be answering those questions.

[The third one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692223/what-is-php-header-explain-to-me-like-i-was-a-5-year-old):

> ... This made me wonder, what are headers, when are they used, both from an HTML perspective but also from some (?) other perspective and why could I remove mine?

The question itself isn't that bad - someone new to web development may not fully understand what headers are, what purpose they serve, how many there are, and how to create one's own.  However, the question is in dire need of editing since both the "explain it to me like a five-year old" bit and the formatting add no value whatsoever.

[The fourth one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10324991/1079354):

> I want to explain what is AND, OR, XOR, zero is false and 1 is true in pure english.
>
> Any tips? links? or may be you can summarize it in your own word will be really helpful to me.

Two things right off the bat:

- It seems to me like there's a lack of true comprehension of the subject material; in order to explain something to someone else, I feel that you should be at familiar enough with the material and concepts.  A question like this gives me no confidence that a concise answer (which was provided) would truly resonate with the OP.
- They're asking for links, which *automatically* raises a red flag in most close voter's minds.

---

There are some of these questions which *should* be closed, and others which are in desperate need of some copy editing.  But by and large, evaluate them on their own merits. Don't try to lump them all together because of a single premise.

Comment: "The question itself isn't that bad - someone new to web development may not fully understand what headers are, what purpose they serve, how many there are, and how to create one's own. However, the question is in dire need of editing since both the "explain it to me like a five-year old" bit and the formatting add no value whatsoever." I heard your call and did it. I think the question nicely conveys that the questioner is not very experienced, so no need to mention it really.

Comment: I agree with evaluate them on their own merits, but I think you're overly harsh in your judgments - and in particular, you're overly harsh in using "too broad".  Large concepts can certainly be broad, but they're also reasonable when asked from the big picture view, in some cases.

Answer (score 28):

Explain Like I'm 5 (Eli5) questions should be reserved for those concepts that are ultimately simple to understand (once you "get" them), but difficult to explain.

Programmers have a tendency to describe things using technical terms and their own, fully-baked understanding, but without addressing the knowledge level of the asker.  This results in a tautological approach that neither illuminates nor explains, an approach that can only be understood by someone who already knows the answer.  Explain like I'm 5 says, "Don't make any assumptions about my current level of knowledge; explain it to me in a way that I can understand it at my own level."

Most powerful programming concepts are simple once you understand them.  They don't require a college degree, your specific vocabulary, or advanced computer science knowledge.  What they do require is *someone who understands them well enough to explain them simply.*  If you can't explain it simply, you just don't know it well enough yet.

> #### The curse of the monad is that once you get the epiphany, once you understand - "oh that's what it is" - you lose the ability to
>   explain it to anyone else.
>
>  -- Douglas Crockford

If you ask a Haskell programmer to explain what a monad is, he'll tell you to go learn Category Theory first.  But it turns out that you don't need Category Theory to understand monads, nor do you need to know Haskell or its type system.  What you do need is [someone who understands monads so well that he can explain them simply.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkZFtimgAcM)

Naturally, I'm not saying you should cater to the lowest common denominator, nor should you provide extended tutelage to someone who hasn't done the work to master the fundamentals.  Questions that ask for such things are too broad.  But I certainly think there is a broad category of computing problems that beg for better descriptive prose, and I think there is room on Stack Overflow for such topics.

Comment: [“A Monad is just a monoid in the category of endofunctors, what’s the big deal?”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870088/a-monad-is-just-a-monoid-in-the-category-of-endofunctors-whats-the-problem)

Comment: this is a really important answer.

Comment: Explain monads simply in 1 hour, hmm... Say you are right and there are some concepts where Eli5 makes sense and we wanted to reserve Eli5 for those questions, how would we select them? Or are you saying we should just leave Eli5 questions alone in general?

Comment: @nwp: The OP should already have a good grounding in the fundamentals of programming.  But don't require him to have an advanced CS degree to understand your answer; if he has that, he probably already knows the answer and wouldn't have asked the question in the first place.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I agree with what you said, I just missed the conclusion. Do we edit out the Eli5-part because it is fluff because every answer should be easily understandable? Do we use Eli5 as a special marker for special questions? Do we just ignore the Eli5-part?

Comment: @nwp: I don't have a problem with folks putting "explain like I'm a 5 year old" in their questions, if it's relevant. I don't think we need an eli5 tag, nor do I have a problem with people editing out the eli5 part if it's not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have asked this question. Explain Like I'm Five (Eli5)

The reason for me asking this question, was I just simply didn't understand ALL explanations previously. I read, and re-read the technical manuals. They all re-iterated the same technical jargon, that was confusing me in the first place.

An Eli5 answer allows someone to get the concept before s/he can build up the technical knowledge.

Comment: I can't see why this is downvoted so much. Noob hate? This is someone talking freely of why they asked like that, moreover, as a last resort after reading the funny manuals. This is actually one of the more valuable contributions to this thread in my mind.

Comment: @SirJane You should learn what votings mean on meta.

Comment: Sorry, but that sounds very high-and-mighty too. Whatever, though, I don't want to argue.

Comment: Which question does *I have asked this question* refer to? I'm pretty sure you meant you didn't understand ANY explanation. Since the technical jargon seems to be required, why not read up on it? There are so many things wrong with this short meta-"answer" alone that I'd say it requires a few hours of explaining stuff every day for a while to get anywhere. Unfortunately stackoverflow is not suitable for that, so there is not much more to do than to close the questions as *lacks minimal understanding*. Try to find someone in your area to teach you stuff and you will eventually get it.

Answer (score -9):

Why not? It's just an indication that he wants to get basic knowledge and wouldn't understand if someone expects some knowledge in this area. Also they are useful for other people who meets this technology for the first time.

Same rules as for usual questions apply.