# Bad Close Vote audit

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review-audits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/8316093

The question is currently closed "Unclear", which is incorrect. While the question is very basic it is extremely clear what is being asked.  I figured this out before voting because I went to the post itself.

What is the correct action here?

Comment: It's unclear for me. I don't really understand what OP means by asking "how it works"? What does he mean? The `/` operator? The `%`? The algorithm behind this?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The review audits are generated automatically, using previous voting stats.

This results the unavoidable possibility of failed review audits. Although you can significanty lower their chance if you don't vote on your own opinion, but your primary goal is to always follow the probable consensus in the case. The result is the maybe sub-optimal situation, that you have significantly better possibilities, if you vote always with the majority opinion, instead of your own.

On my opinion, don't bother on a single failed audit, if

- it was caused by a probably bad review audit
- or it happened because you have a minority opinion in the question.

On my opinion, the only problem if you committed a mistake, which can happen especially if we make a lot of reviews at once, and don't give them their required attention.

Comment: Why does this have two downvotes? It's clearly a better explanation of the current reality than the other +4 answer?

Comment: @JimGarrison Because it is critical. It doesn't matter if it is polite or not. People here don't like critical views. You can't build a castle from shit, you need stones - well, here is another, this time not so polite critic.

Comment: Curious. I do not interpret the answer as critical, just pointing out a (well known) flaw in the system.

Comment: @JimGarrison For people voting always with the masses for "advancement", yes it is an attack. Around 1-2 years ago the SO did much worser, it had got tens of downvotes at the time and a lot of people complaining for the "ranting". Now this +1/-2 is nearly okay.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this MSO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions), questions that are a code dump with a request for an explanation of said dump are too broad. I suppose it doesn't really matter that it was closed as unclear because that not much of a stretch either. It certainly doesn't make sense to have bad questions reopened just because they were closed for the wrong reason.