# Why is this audit question not 'Too broad'?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

[One of my recent audits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9243743) was an "explain how this code works" type question, and I initially was not sure how to handle it.  After sifting through meta posts on the subject, it seems like the consensus was that those type of questions should be flagged as "too broad".  After flagging it, I failed the audit - apparently I should have marked it as "looks okay".

I certainly don't think it is a *bad* question, but I doubt its usefulness to future Stack Overflow users.

Was I incorrect, or is this a poor audit question?

Comment: I won't argue that the answer is *very* useful - but does a good answer change the inherent usefulness of a question?

Comment: Biggest issue with that question is the title.... "How does this ____ work" is an awful title because you now need to read the question to see the actual issue.  If it could be fixed to describe "this" in a couple of words, probably would make the question ok since you now make it a searchable.  I just don't know if it is possible since I don't really know the subject matter.

Comment: [How to handle “Explain how this ${code dump} works” questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896/839601)

Comment: @psubsee2003, the title has been updated.