# Stack Overflow for show'n'tell

Tags: discussion, questions

Is it appropriate to post as a question something along the lines of, "I wrote this really cool thing. Can you work out what it does?" (and post the code).

My reason to think yes is, it still spreads knowledge - it serves the interests of answerers and readers.

Stack Overflow does allow answering your own question, i.e. asking questions you know the answer to.

[How to handle "Explain how this ${code dump} works" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253894/11682469) deals with 'code dump' questions in general, but I am of course referring to posting a minimal snippet with no unneccessary details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Breaking down "too broad"/"needs more focus" and trying to understand it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-needs-more-focus-and-trying-to-understand-it)

Comment: Related: [How to handle “Explain how this ${code dump} works” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253894/11682469)

Comment: Asking us to work out how something works you wrote, when you know how it works, feels like a very odd question; like you're trying to test us.

Comment: @JeanneDark It's certainly not the *same* question. If you mean, every such question is automatically unfocused, I don't think it is. A piece of code does one specific thing and can only be explained so many ways.

Comment: Do you have a specific example in mind, or are you wanting to post such a question? This meta question seems too broad for a conclusive answer

Comment: If you have working code you can have it reviewed at CodeReview.se. Just posting code so we can admire it is not a good fit for SO. Use your blog. If you have a puzzle for us to solve: try [puzzling.se](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @charlietfl I don't want to post if it is out of scope. I will if it will be considered as contributing to this discussion.

Comment: Do you think your question will be useful to future readers?

Comment: @khelwood That would be the point. Seeing interesting code explained is generally a way of getting some depth of insight.

Comment: Rephrased: Will it solve a problem that future readers might be searching for an answer to? It does not sound like it will.

Comment: @khelwood Directly, probably not. I guess it could be rephrased to do that.

Comment: Downvotes on Meta are different than on Main. They can express disagreement with the question, as well as the quality/utility of the post itself.

Comment: The downvotes may have arisen from a suspicion that SO is being misused as homework/competition fodder.  The thing is, users download, copy and plag code, the try to con  other SO users into explaining how it works so that thet can hand it in with the impression of having some knowledge and of having done some work:(

Comment: Since you mentioned "I wrote this really cool thing. Can you work out what it does?", you might be interested in our sister site [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Votes). Probably not for challenging them to understand your code, but more for browsing more "really cool thing" code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a common misconception of Stack Overflow... That it can be co-opted to serve everyone's idea of what a "knowledge-sharing" site (or "community of programmers") should look like.

The idea behind Stack Overflow is this: if you create a focused list of questions that are *answerable,* you can collect a repository of information that is *useful to others,* not just the asker.  "Show and Tell" doesn't do that; if I'm looking for an answer to my specific programming question, I'm not interested in "Show and Tell."

The closest thing we have to a "show-and-tell" site is [Code Review](https://CodeReview.stackexchange.com), but it is still tightly-focused on a specific set of objectives.