# My question asking how Press & Hold Captcha works is getting close voted. Is Stack Overflow the wrong place to ask how something works?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, close-reasons

[How do "Press & Hold Captcha work?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74407461/how-does-this-press-hold-bot-filter-captcha-via-user-interaction-work) has negative votes and is being closed & I cannot see the reason - quality, clarity, duplicate, off-topic, etc.

Answer (score 27):

It is very clearly inappropriate for Stack Overflow. It was closed just now as seeking third-party resources, presumably because of:

> Are there any frameworks to build such CAPTCHAs?

which is pretty straightforward.

However, I would have voted to close as **Needs More Focus**.

> I found generated code that was hard to follow.

We cannot possibly tell you anything about how the code works without seeing it. But even then, [that is still not a proper question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/). We don't know *specifically what* you don't understand about it.

Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**. As such, we cannot discuss with you the broad-strokes, top-down system design of an entire program (or program feature, or web site feature...). "How does this kind of CAPTCHA work?" is no more answerable than "how can I write a simple text adventure in Python?" Even with that level of specificity, there are any number of unspoken design decisions.

> What is the mechanism of this kind of a User Interaction CAPTCHA? How does it ensure that bots do not slip through by sending fake User Agent strings, skipping javascript execution etc?

This is, quite clearly, multiple questions in one. Even supposing that we *have a concrete reason to expect* that forging the user agent string, conditionally skipping javascript etc. would *matter* to the CAPTCHA (it is *your* responsibility to *explain the scheme you have in mind*), each of these is a separate design concern that would motivate a separate question. If those questions were on topic. Which they probably aren't.

Finally: please [keep research expectations in mind](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). If I wanted to know how press-and-hold captcha works, I would [start with a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+does+press-and-hold+captcha+work). If you want to find a framework, [similarly](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=create+captcha+framework). If you want to know what data is sent, then look at your network activity - "several XHR beacon.js requests" is where a proper investigation begins, not where it ends. *When* are the requests made? How does that relate to your interaction with the button? Did you try to look up what beacon.js does?