# Are questions asking about the purpose of a particular snippet of code within a non-documented library within the scope of the site?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

Are questions asking about the purpose of a particular snippet of code within a non-documented, *well-known* library/package/repository  (e.g. [DeepSort](https://github.com/nwojke/deep_sort/)) within the scope of the site?

Comment: Related: [How to handle "Explain how this ${code dump} works" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions)

Comment: Maybe, maybe not depending on how broad of an explanation is required. But even when it is on topic expect a few, "Have you stepped through it with a debugger?" comments.

Comment: Even if they are, I give such questions very little chance of being well-received. They are not useful to other people, they are more curiosity questions.

Comment: What do you mean? You talk about a question, regarding a code snippet inside some library and as a reference you mention the entire library itself.

Comment: @Dominique I see. I misplaced the e.g.

Comment: Questions are ***required** to be self-contained*. If the full context necessary for a subject matter expert to understand the question and provide an answer isn't in the question, then it's off-topic and should be closed (typically as "unclear"/"needs details or clarity", but for debugging questions, "needs debugging details" may be more specific). [This is just a general statement of the limits of scope for the site and shouldn't be taken as saying if the type of question being asked about is on-topic or off-topic when the necessary context is fully contained within the question.]

Comment: @Makyen So if I include all the the snippets of code that call or are called by the snippet of code in question, the question would be on-topic?

Comment: @MehdiCharife I thought I was *really* clear that I wasn't making a statement about that. I was just stating that if it's *necessary* for subject mater experts to go off the question page to get context about the question that's not in the question in order to answerer, then it's *definitely* off-topic/not in scope for the site.

Comment: I understand. So being self-contained is just a necessary, though not sufficient, condition for being on-topic.

Comment: Well. That explained what the ubiquitous SME stands in for. I had the context figured out, but not what it actually acronymized.

Comment: Side note: _SME_ is one of the entries in the [Stack Exchange Glossary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/671985) - a resource which has helped me understand much of the terminology I see on Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow. @user4581301

Comment: I absolutely think this is correct.  Furthermore, if it's not allowed, people could just try to 'sneak' a question in via a 'flaw' in the code, and ask indirectly.

Comment: In addition to including the *complete* snippet they are wondering about so the complete context is self-contained I also try to get the OP to explain what *specific* part of *that* code they are struggling to understand, any specific part that isn't meeting their expectations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions asking what a snippet of code *does* are OK as long as the snippet includes enough code to be reproducible (as Makyen mentioned in comments above, if I have to go off-site to find the answer, then the snippet/question is not self-contained and reproducible. You can't expect users to guess at what type a variable may be or what its contents are if it is not declared in that snippet, or what a function call will do if that function's definition is missing, for example.

Questions asking *why* a snippet of code was written a certain way or included where it was may *not* be OK depending on the specific question being asked. We can't guess as to motivations behind design decisions.

Comment: What's the point of asking what the code does, rather than just **trying it**? The question really needs to be something more specific, i.e. why it did X instead of Y (with an explicit Y!) in circumstance Z.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Running code doesn't always tell you what the code does. In fact I would wager that running _most_ code won't tell you what it does. If it did, we also would never need things like code comments or explanations in answers; we'd just prefer code-only answers here.